# The carousel image could not fit to full width in React

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

[image: The image could only be half of the width]

```
import { Carousel, Image } from 'react-bootstrap'

<Carousel pause='hover' className='bg-primary mb-4'>
          {data?.products.map((product) => (
            <Carousel.Item key={product._id}>
              <Link to={`/product/${product._id}`}>
                <Image src={product.image} alt={product.name} className='img-fluid' />
                <Carousel.Caption className='carousel-caption'>
                  <h2 className='text-white text-right'>
                    {product.name} (${product.price})
                  </h2>
                </Carousel.Caption>
              </Link>
            </Carousel.Item>
          ))}
      </Carousel>
```

I am trying to put the image with the full width instead of only half of the width by react bootstrap carousel. Even I added the `img-fluid` on the image property, it still could not extend to the full width size. Any solutions that could have the image extend to full width of carousel?

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap, .img-fluid applies max-width: 100%; and height: auto;

Instead of max-width, you may want to manually set its width and object-fit

Comment: So instead I using ```img-fluid``` I should use custom css to adjust?

Comment: style={{ width: "100%", objectFit: "cover" }}

try to add this attribute in the Image tag, you can also set height if you want to restrict the height of the carousell

Comment: I may want to keep the same height remain unchanged and width to 100%